# Cassandra multiple tables with same partitionkey

Tags: cassandra

I have two tables in Cassandra which have the same partition key. e.g.

```
table department (
  deptId text,
  name text,
  primary key (deptId) 
)

table employee (
   empid text,
   name text,
   deptid text,
   primary key (deptid, empid)
)
```

If I insert records to both these tables with the same deptId, will they be co-located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the murmur3 (given default partitioner) of the data would be the same so it would use same ring position. Assuming they are in same keyspace or have same replication factor they would colocate on same replicas.